# Pulling variables off site that uses the same name

Tags: python, json, regex

Basically I am now trying to pull all the `SKU`s from the `sortedOptions` section only. I was told it was json, unsure if that correct. right now I'm only pulling the first one. What do I need to specify to pull all of them? 
I initially tried using regex and wasn't pulling any info, i was then told that it was json and i needed to use json. thus far this has been the only method i have used to be able to pull anything from the website.

then my next step is to pull the `stock status` and `name` with in that same section only.

CODE:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('https://randomwebsite.com/')
pull = r.json()
print " "

string = json.dumps(pull)

parsed_json = json.loads(string)
print parsed_json['name']
print parsed_json['SKU']
```

output from site:

```
{
"ID": "281460",
"SKU": "281460",
"isVisible": true,
"isOption": false,
"parentSKU": null,
"trackingSKU": "281460",
"name": "NIKE Air Vapormax",
"model": null,
"brand": {
"id": 
"ID": "9D63FD8C31DBD53AB2A9D51F4D9DBBCA",
"name": "NIKE",
"clientID": null,
"sortOrder": null,
"image": null,
"target": "",
"filters": {
"brandname": "nike"
}
},
"sortedOptions": [
{
"name": "5.5",
"product": {
"SKU": "281460.463725",
"isDefault": false,
"price": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"previousPrice": null,
"RRP": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"costPrice": null,
"taxCode": null,
"taxRate": null,
"stockStatus": "IN STOCK",
"colour": "",
"colourDescription": "GRY/GRY-SPECK",
"size": null,
"exactSize": null,
"sortOrder": "1",
"optionTypes": [
"UK Size"
]
},
"isLeaf": true
},
{
"name": "6",
"product": {
"SKU": "281460.595347",
"isDefault": false,
"price": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"previousPrice": null,
"RRP": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"costPrice": null,
"taxCode": null,
"taxRate": null,
"stockStatus": "IN STOCK",
"colour": "",
"colourDescription": "GRY/GRY-SPECK",
"size": null,
"exactSize": null,
"sortOrder": "2",
"optionTypes": [
"UK Size"
]
},
"isLeaf": true
},
{
"name": "6.5",
"product": {
"SKU": "281460.463895",
"isDefault": false,
"price": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"previousPrice": null,
"RRP": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"costPrice": null,
"taxCode": null,
"taxRate": null,
"stockStatus": "IN STOCK",
"colour": "",
"colourDescription": "GRY/GRY-SPECK",
"size": null,
"exactSize": null,
"sortOrder": "3",
"optionTypes": [
"UK Size"
]
},
"isLeaf": true
},
{
"name": "7.5",
"product": {
"SKU": "281460.595350",
"isDefault": false,
"price": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"previousPrice": null,
"RRP": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"costPrice": null,
"taxCode": null,
"taxRate": null,
"stockStatus": "IN STOCK",
"colour": "",
"colourDescription": "GRY/GRY-SPECK",
"size": null,
"exactSize": null,
"sortOrder": "5",
"optionTypes": [
"UK Size"
]
},
"isLeaf": true
},
{
"name": "8",
"product": {
"SKU": "281460.595352",
"isDefault": false,
"price": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"previousPrice": null,
"RRP": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"costPrice": null,
"taxCode": null,
"taxRate": null,
"stockStatus": "IN STOCK",
"colour": "",
"colourDescription": "GRY/GRY-SPECK",
"size": null,
"exactSize": null,
"sortOrder": "6",
"optionTypes": [
"UK Size"
]
},
"isLeaf": true
},
{
"name": "9",
"product": {
"SKU": "281460.595359",
"isDefault": false,
"price": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"previousPrice": null,
"RRP": {
"amount": "180.00",
"currency": "GBP"
},
"costPrice": null,
"taxCode": null,
"taxRate": null,
"stockStatus": "IN STOCK",
"colour": "",
"colourDescription": "GRY/GRY-SPECK",
"size": null,
"exactSize": null,
"sortOrder": "8",
"optionTypes": [
"UK Size"
]
},
"isLeaf": true
},
```

Comment: Why do you take the converted objects, turn them back into a JSON string and then back again into objects?

Comment: it was giving me a error indicating it needed to be a string, if you have a more direct method please let me know. this is the only way i have been able to pull info from this page

Comment: Your code doesn't work.

Comment: @coldspeed the code above outputs this   NIKE Air Vapormax
281460            https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxe7q8ksuw5lz9e/Screenshot%202017-08-05%2011.21.01.png?dl=0

Comment: When I try to run your code the line `r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)` results in a `requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)` error.

Comment: The JSON shown is also invalid. Near the beginning there's an `"id":` followed immediately by an `"ID":`—which isn't valid JSON (or Python dictionary) syntax.

Comment: duc: That's all very interesting—but you need to fix _this_ question. Entering the url on the address bar of your browser is not the same as using `requests` to get the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151155/discussion-between-duc-hathaway-and-martineau).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you provided is not valid. Anyway, I assume that "sortedOptions" is a list. So this should enlight you:

```
for option in parsed_json['sortedOptions']:
    print option.keys()
```

For a more complete answer, please provide a valid json. The one tou provided is **not**. Hint: use `curl` or `wget`.

Comment: thanks i used this off what you said and got it working  --                          ' for option in data['sortedOptions']:    
                print(option['product']['SKU'])'